# Reportbuilder - Test Connection Succeeds but still get Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql, connection, reportbuilder

I'm setting up my connection in Report builder and all goes as plans

[image]

But then after accepting the connection properties, when I try and test it It gives me that error.

[image]

Why would report builder default to the that login credentials?? I am logged on as the user that has access to the database and I've confirmed it. (Logged onto sql with my credentials.)

Might there be something im not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the credentials tab and make sure the credentials used to log on is correct.
Also make sure that **Use as Windows credentials** is checked.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Didn't even see that.

Answer (score 1):

This was the same case for me. For security reasons I could not use sql account so I must use my windows credentials. So what I have done is just clicked on "Disconnect" link in bottom-left of report designer which was showing my report server link. That did the trick for me. Hope this helps some one.